# Highcharts on rails app renders twice every time it's loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in a Rails 4 application.  Every time a chart is loaded, it is rendered twice.  For example, if I click a link to render the partial containing a particular chart, the chart will display once, and then display again.  The app is doing twice the work it should be doing, so I'd like to fix this double rendering issue

Here's an example call to one of the charts that's doing this:

**View:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
    <%= link_to "Cumulative Customers", cumulative_customers_path, id: "bookings_per_customer", remote: true %>
</button>
```

**cumulative_customers.js.erb:**

```
$('.chart-display').html("");
$('.chart-display').append("<%= j render :partial => 'cumulative_customer_chart' %>");
$('.chart-display').append("<%= j render :partial => 'cumulative_customer_scripts' %>");
```

**_cumulative_customer_chart.html.erb:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "cumulative_customers_chart" %>
</div>
```

**_cumulative_customer_scripts.html.erb:**

```
<script>
$(function () {  
  new Highcharts.Chart({  

    chart: { 
        renderTo: 'cumulative_customers_chart',
        height: 600
    }, 
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }, 

    title: { text: 'Customer Accounts by Day' },  
    xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },  
    yAxis: {  
      title: { text: 'Customer Accounts' }  
    },  
     series: [
        {  
            type: 'area',
        name: 'Customer Accounts',
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,  
      pointStart: <%= get_point_start %>,  
      data: <%= cumulative_customers_count(params[:filter_period]) %>  
    }]  

  });  
});
```

I don't see anything to indicate that Highcharts is being queried more than once... Can anyone please provide some insight?

Comment: As I see in the $('.chart-display').append("<%= j render :partial => 'cumulative_customer_chart' %>"); you add one div, and in <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "cumulative_customers_chart" %> second time. Let me know if Im wrong or not, becasue Im not rails expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.  This only happens in development and not in production, and was caused by precompiling assets into public/assets for production.